# Can you invoke a method in Cypress using dynamically instantiated objects?

Tags: nested, invoke, cypress

I'm trying to write e2e tests with Cypress and would like to dynamically be able to intantiate objects and use them as parameters for the `invoke` method.

The subject under test is a SPA with a redux store. For debugging (and possibly e2e testing), I have a `window.debug` object. The debug object exposes a `dispatchAction(action: Action)` method and properties that return classes, for instance `Actions.SetMenu`.

So on the browsers console I can call something like this to dispatch an action:`debug.dispatchAction(new debug.Actions.SetMenu({ menu }))`

For Cypress I need something like the following:

```
let setMenuAction;
cy.window()
  .its('debug')
  .then(debug => {
    const SetMenu = debug.Actions.SetMenu;
    setMenuAction = new SetMenu({ menu });
    console.log(setMenuAction);
    return debug;
  })
  .invoke('dispatchAction', setMenuAction);
```

But the above doesn't work. Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying?

Edit: Got it to work, was an async problem:

```
cy.window()
  .its('debug.Actions.SetMenu')
  .then(SetMenu => {
    cy.window()
      .its('debug')
      .invoke('dispatchAction', new SetMenu({ menu }));
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cy.window()
  .its('debug.Actions.SetMenu')
  .then(SetMenu => {
    cy.window()
      .its('debug')
      .invoke('dispatchAction', new SetMenu({ menu }));
  })
```